# Getting each user in table and using them where module =

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table: tbl_module_bid

image:

[image]

you see users: Ali2,Ali,blackbone,dickface,mhmd
let's call for each one of them it's called $player and the sql query I wanna use in:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `bbcsystem`.`tbl_admin` SET games_played = games_played + 1 WHERE username = $player");
```

I also don't want them to be duplicated
I tried using this script below:

```
//Update Game Played (not working very good):
    $num_qry        =   "Select DISTINCT *  From tbl_module_bid where  user = '".$_SESSION['LOGIN_BALANCE_FRONT']['name']."' AND module = '$mod_id'  order by bid asc";
    $get_pick       =   $db->get_results($num_qry,ARRAY_A);
                foreach($get_pick as $arr_pic)
                {
                    $player = $arr_pic['user'];
                    mysql_query("UPDATE `bbcsystem`.`tbl_admin` SET games_played = games_played + 1 WHERE username = $player");
                }
```

Comment: I have always wondered why people are prefixing their SQL table names with `tbl_`. As if it was not clear that it is a table.

Comment: So what is your problem or error, whatever?

Comment: @u_mulder: it seems like they want us to tell them how to say `SELECT ... FROM tbl_module_bid WHERE module = $module GROUP BY user`.

Comment: Yes, could you kindly clarify: what is wrong with that query? what is your goal? what results do you expect from your query?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov this is an old subject when atiques database (if we can call it as databases) listed all objects (when asked) without any distinction, so you put some info on the object name to see what it is... But this is from ooooooold times, nowadays this isn't needed anymore.

Comment: I just hate when my post get -2, it makes it goes very slower...

Comment: Please help me guys, it's really urgent :)

Comment: Okay, Ill pay 5$ worth of bitcoins to whoever helps me !!!